# oh my zsh theme is not change in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal, oh-my-zsh

I have an `Ubuntu 16.04` on my `VMware Workstation`. Installed some theme like `macbuntu` and `macOS Sierra theme` and also installed `zsh` and `oh my zsh`.

Now i want to change its theme (`oh-my-zsh` theme) for terminal. change it to `avit` ar `cloud` and so on. but when I change the `ZSH_THEME="avit"` and run `zsh` or even run `source ~/.zshrc` it will not change the theme, nor do when log out and log in again. why is that? what should I do?

I have installed the `oh-my-zsh` for my own user and made a symlink to the config file(`/home/my_username/.zshrc`) and placed it inside `/root` directory as my root user home directory is `/root`, all of this is because I wouldn't change it twice. I have only two users, me and my root user so that's not a security issue for me.

why my config does not affect?

Comment: `I have installed the oh-my-zsh for my own user and made a symlink to the config file(/home/my_username/.zshrc) and placed it inside /root directory as my root user home directory is /root, all of this is because I wouldn't change it twice.` I really don't know if this would work. Try installing oh-my-zsh for your user and for root separately.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem. I uninstalled the oh-my-zsh and installed it again and its working. by the way the symlink is working for su user